# Why in-line alignment won't work on Opera?

Tags: html, css

Why in-line alignment won't work on Opera?

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/KKEKW/

**With Firefox or Safari it looks fine just like this. This is how it looks what I want.**

[image]

**With Opera it will be all straight up just like this. I dont want it.**

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class ="social">
    <div class ="row">  
        <div class="twitter">
            twitter content
        </div>
        <div class="facebook">
            facebook content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class ="row">
        <div class="google">
            google content
        </div>
        <div class="instagram">
            instagram content
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.social {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 90px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}


div.row{    
}

div.twitter {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:inline-block;
}

div.facebook {
  float: left;
  width: 170px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:inline-block;
}

div.google {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
}

div.instrgram {
  float: left;
  width: 170px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Adding `width: 400px;` to `div.social` made it work on Opera. And IE9.

Comment: @Ove I don't want width for `div.social` because it should be responsive. Is there any other way to do?

Comment: I don't know if there's another way to do it, but this seems to work.

Comment: @Foo The fact that you've got your dimensions specified in px makes it fairly unresponsive (what happens if the user overrides the font-size so they can read it?).

Answer (score 2):

`float:left` and `display:inline-block` are contradicting each other. If you float an element, it makes the `display` property irrelevant.

So remove either the `float` or the `display` from your elements. Don't try to use them both at once; it won't work the way you expect.

Anyway, it looks to me as if you could achieve what you want by specifying the `display:inline-block` on `.row` rather than the `.twitter`, `.facebook`, etc elements.

Comment: Opera is fussier than other browsers when it comes to changing the display on a floated element.  You also have a typo in your `.instagram` class (you have `.instrgram`).  http://jsfiddle.net/KKEKW/3/

Comment: @cimmanon The problem with your code is, if any of the content in left become longer strength, the left edge of right content will be shifted to right all the way. It affects to the another content in different row. That's why I had each row. Could you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but it worked for me (with less CSS/HTML too):

HTML:

```
<section class="left">
    <div>Twitter</div>
    <div>Google</div>
</section>

<section class="right">
    <div>Facebook</div>
    <div>Instagram</div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: left;
}
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Eze5X/).

Comment: The problem with that is, if any of the content in left become longer strength, the left edge of right content will be shifted to right all the way. It affects to the another content in different row. That's why I had each row.