# How can I always start at new line for every 2 blocks?

Tags: css

Why in-line alignment won't work on Opera? It's all straight up.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/KKEKW/

**With Firefox or Safari it looks fine just like this. This is how it looks what I want.**

[image]

**With Opera it will be all straight up just like this. I dont want it.**

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class ="social">
    <div class ="row">  
        <div class="twitter">
            twitter content
        </div>
        <div class="facebook">
            facebook content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class ="row">
        <div class="google">
            google content
        </div>
        <div class="instagram">
            instagram content
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.social {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 90px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}


div.row{    
}

div.twitter {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:inline-block;
}

div.facebook {
  float: left;
  width: 170px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:inline-block;
}

div.google {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
}

div.instrgram {
  float: left;
  width: 170px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

**The output that I want**

```
twitter content ewfe(20px margin)facebook conten adhfhefjw
google content ewffewfewfewfew(20px margin)instagram content dwqwqqwfqwe
```

Comment: Did you create a new account just so you can repost this exact question right down to the misspelled class name?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645844/why-in-line-alignment-wont-work-on-opera

Comment: @cimmanon Please take a look at comments list. Because no one didn't answer anymore and there was not right answer:(

Comment: @cimmanon I've just updated answer. Please see the bottom. This is I was looking for. Please.

Answer (score 1):

A styled, unordered list can do this for you.

Give your `LI` a fixed width, give your `UL` twice as much. Use `float:left` on your `LI`.

```
<div class ="social">
<ul>
    <li>twitter content</li>
    <li>facebook content</li>
    <li>google content</li>
    <li>instagram content</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
social ul, social li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;    
}

.social ul {
    width:500px;
}

.social li {
    width:250px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Even better: it's now in the above answer. Lists make great, versatile containers. See my tutorial: http://preview.moveable.com/jm/ilovelists/

Comment: Thanks for posting answer. However in your answer. all the width will be set the same. I don't want that. I want everything shifted to left as left as possible. then everything has to be started at new line for every 2 blocks

Comment: Then you need to use a different technique.

Comment: can't you just start at new line for every 2 blocks? Isn't it that easy? 1. Every object should be started at new line for every 2 objects. 2. Every object should be in left as left as possible. 3. If possible I want right-margin width 20px between objects

Comment: The idea here is to alow the CSS to do the formatting. With variable-length items you have to insert your line-breaks manually.